# Context error when displaying toast from a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, toast

I want to display a toast when the user selects an option from a spinner. I keep getting the error, "Cannot resolve method makeText". I have tried using **getApplicationContext()** and typing **MainActivity.this** but either the same error remains or I get an additional error that states,

"**Incompatible Types. Required: android.widget.Toast**".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView equalSign;
private Spinner conversionSpinner, unitOneSpinner, unitTwoSpinner;
private EditText unitOneEditText, unitTwoEditText;
private String[] selectedList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> conversionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, conversion_types);
    conversionSpinner.setAdapter(conversionAdapter);
    conversionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a toast object. Just write

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It should work. Please let me know if it does.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you. I don't know why I was getting context errors when I was declaring a toast object.

Comment: Toast toast is an object instance of Toast, and Toast.makeText() is a static reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the line of code instead of it

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I've tried that but for some reason it gives me an Incompatible Types error.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers in this case to an `OnItemSelectedListener`. So you need to change

```
Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the `.show` method has no **return** value.

Answer (score 0):

> Incompatible Types. Required: android.widget.Toast

Because assigning `void` to `Toast` object.

As see here: [Toast.show()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#show()) method return `void` instead of `Toast`. do it as:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or call `show` after creating Toast Object as:

```
Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toastMessage.show();
```

Comment: This also worked for me when I tried it. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Chris: good if working and also if u know why error is happening thanks